# jQuery qtip - loading an image into the qtip via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, qtip

I'm using the jQuery [qtip](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) plugin. I want the content of the qtip to be an image, loaded dynamically.

The url I'm using works. If I go to the url, I see an image.

However, the qtip shows something... weird. Here is the result:

[image]

Any ideas why this would happen?

---

Edit

This is the entire Response Header (via Chrome inspector):

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Cache-Control:no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:5690
Content-Type:image/gif; charset=binary
Date:Thu, 09 Sep 2010 17:35:48 GMT
Expires:Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=2
Last-Modified:Thu, 09 Sep 2010 17:35:48 GMT
Pragma:no-cache
Server:nginx/0.8.31
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.2.11
```

Comment: Is it possible the page you're loading is not using utf-8 encoding?

Comment: The page is just an image, not html with an image on it.

Comment: Just for fun: can you check the content type the server returns for the image?

Comment: @Tomalak Content-Type:image/gif; charset=binary (I'm gonna post the entire response in a sec)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably need to point the qTip plugin to an url that will return an html fragment containing a link to the image and not directly to the image. The fragment might look like this:

```
<div>
    <img src="/images/someimage.jpg" alt="" />
</div>
```

I don't think that qTip supports fetching images directly. Think of it: an AJAX request is sent and if the server returns a binary array representing the image using javascript this binary array cannot be shown (unless you use the [data uri scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) which is not very common).

Comment: I can definitely do this. I can load the image via ajax and then pass it to qtip. But, I'd like to actually use qtip's built in ajax querying, if possible. And the image is coming from an API, so I can't change that page either. But, this will be my solution if nothing closer to the problem comes around.

Comment: Could you explain how are you doing this using plain AJAX?

Comment: Currently I'm just using qtip's ajax call -- 

content: {
                  text: '<img src="/public/images/core/util/loading.gif" /> Loading User Info',
                  url: tip_url
               },

Comment: @hookedonwinter, my question was how do you send an AJAX request to an url returning an image using `$.ajax` and showing this image in the browser?

Comment: Oh, I see what you're trying to say.. Ya, I don't know how I'd do that. I think your solution might be the way to go. Testing now.